# How to proceed discussion with a company about internship

Tags: internship

I received acceptance letter for internship and am awaiting for final offer letter.
While discussing the period to finalize offer letter over an email, I inquired possibility of part-time to extend the period.

I haven't heard from the team manager about 10 days, so I followed up about the status and they replied they hoped to finalize soon.

After a week, as I still do not hear anything from team, I asked them again the possibility to arrange a call to finalize period (not considering) & discuss about topic.

It's already been 10 days, but I never heard from them in total 17 days.
I felt like I've request number of things without any organization.
How should I reach out again to proceed my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried enough, so now its their duty to do it.
There could be 2 reasons,

First: They have already dropped the idea of hiring you. So you should move on and get urself a another job.

Second: They don't take requests(email) seriously. These shows that they are not professional. So you should probably drop the idea of continue to work with them. Because these can even happen during your internship.

Do remember one thing, the grace time for any email response is 3-7 working days. I assume the working days has been passed(17days).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh really? It is a big company. Can they just send an offer and change to drop it without any notice? I already declined another offers. I do not know how to do

Comment: The role you were taking on is no valid, or is being already performed by someone else in the company. Or may this is the scenrio: The person resigned for role, and then they hired you but then something happen that they decided to drop the role.

Comment: "big company" but they are all still humans!

Comment: I see. I hope to receive confirmation from a company. Is it okay if I make a phone call to HR team to confirm about my status? or should I just an email?

Comment: If you wish to clarify, give them a call. But I will say, you have tried enough!